# Можно ли запустить один файл отдельно в xcode?

Tags: swift, xcode

Имеется проект, содержащий несколько файлов. Вопрос следующий: возможно ли без полного компилирования запустить, скажем, отдельный файл, чтобы в нем проверить работоспособность некоторого метода?

Comment: Обычно для этого используют Playground

Comment: Можно unit test написать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если у вас простой код без зависимостей, вы можете запускать этот отдельный файл через командую строку:

```
~ swift /Users/user/TestSwift11/main1.swift
```

Hello, World 1

```
~ swift /Users/user/TestSwift11/main2.swift
```

Hello, World 2